# How to print all Info in InteractiveMarkerFeedback

Tags: ros, visualization-msgs, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the [Simple Interactive Marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Writing%20a%20Simple%20Interactive%20Marker%20Server) tutorial and I try to visualize all the information I can get from the pointer. But catkin_make complains the function  is not existent, but the [class template](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/ric_mc/html/classvisualization__msgs_1_1InteractiveMarkerFeedback.html) says otherwise. Headers and package.xml and cmakelist should be ok.

How to go from here:

```
 void processMarkerFeedback(const
                           visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedbackConstPtr
                           & feedbackPtr)
{
  unsigned char buff[1000];
  feedbackPtr->serialize(buff);// fail
  printf("%s\n", buff);
```

catkin_make says

> error: ‘const struct visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedback_std::allocator<void >’ has no member named ‘serialize’

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240221/how-to-print-all-info-in-interactivemarkerfeedback/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use kinetic, and it looks like they dissolved the header file [InteractiveMarkerFeedback](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/ric_mc/html/InteractiveMarkerFeedback_8h_source.html). 
[Cannot locate it](https://www.google.de/#q=InteractiveMarkerFeedback.h+site:http:%2F%2Fdocs.ros.org%2Fkinetic%2F) anymore. Basically it was *only* about (de-) serialization.

Probably to reduce src files, the new interactive marker definition is [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz/html/c++/interactive__marker_8h.html).

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this is the issue, but the class template that you link to is from hydro. What version of ROS are you using?

I'm using indigo, which apparently also [has serialize and deserialize methods](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/ric_mc/html/classvisualization__msgs_1_1InteractiveMarkerFeedback.html) (which I didn't know, so thanks!). I don't know if jade or later retain that API for messages, so that's something to check.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-07-25**:
mmh, I will check